# Migrate from CRUD to DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, crud, data-modeling

Now I want to try to start from the objects of my model according to the dictates DDD but I have some difficulty in understanding how to migrate my thought patterns because I can not turn the examples that I find lying around on my specific case .

My main concept are the activities , each activity has an indicative code , a description , a status that changes over time and a quarter each Result.

Users want to be able to see the history of all the states hired from the activities, with the dates on which the changes were made . In addition, they also want to be able to create new states, change the description of the existing ones and possibly prevent the use of some of these while maintaining the value for the previous activities .

Each quarter, users want to be able to insert an Result that contains Outcome and recommendations, a rating and the date of formulation of the outcome .

The ratings must be a list freely maintainable by users.

Thinking to my old way I would create classes like this:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ID;
    public string Desc;
    public IList<ActivityStatus> ActivityStatusList;
    public IList<Result> ResultList;
}

public class ActivityStatus
{
    public Activity Activity;
    public Status Status;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
}

public class Status
{
    public int ID;
    public string Desc;
    public bool Valid;
}

public class Result
{
    public Activity Activity;
    public int Quarter;
    public string Outcome;
    public string Recommendations;
    public Rating Rating;
}

public class Rating
{
    public int ID;
    public string Desc;
    public bool Valid;
}
```

than i will implement a DataAccessLayer mapping this class to a new db (created from this class) with NHibernate and add repository to grant user CRUD operation to all of this object

According to DDD are there better ways?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to read the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) or at least the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

DDD is about focussing on domain logic and modelling this first - in an object-oriented way. Persistence is a technical concern, which should not be the starting point of your design and (usually) not determine, how you will design your domain classes.

Comment: i read DDD by eric evans, .NET Domain-Driven Design with C#: Problem - Design - Solution by Tim McCarthy and Domain Driven Design by Casey Charlton but my question still remain

Comment: @gt.guybrush: Really? I find this a little hard to believe. What you are suggesting as your starting point is exactly, what Evans is arguing against: an 'anemic domain model' with only data and no behavior (methods). Pick the book up again and try to understand, what an 'aggregate root' is. You should determine 'aggregate roots' way before you start modelling persistence.

Comment: with those requirements you can not think in classes other than the ones I've written, even without thinking about CRUD. Maybe all stems from the fact that for me, for example, put an Activity in a certain status means creating an object ActivityStatus wich have some property, but I can not see an alternative and I really want to figure out if in fact there are

Comment: i read about aggregate root but I do not understand how i can use: Activity would be an ideal AR but as I can isolate the other items inside if users want to be free to modify them freely without going through any activity? It 's my main problem

Comment: P.S. i have method for adding and removing elements from lists and validation logic in set method but do not change the terms of the problem

Comment: But that's the whole point of an aggregate root! You have to "go through it" to manipulate child entities. Your users obviously don't care, which objects are manipulated under the hood. It's you, who has to assure that in your object-oriented design. Anyway, I don't mean to sound rude. I think that your difficulties might partially come from a focus on CRUD-based UIs and the so-called "object-relational impedance mismatch" in the DAL. It's hard to squeeze an object-oriented domain layer between those.

Comment: And maybe, just maybe, your domain is so simple, that a DDD approach would be overkill. There's no shame in using a simpler design, if the domain is simple.

Comment: @gt.guybrush The hardest part (and the essence) of DDD is modelling. Even when you see a code sample you're actually seeing the result but _not_ the design process. The point of DDD is thinking in Domain language using Domain concepts expressed as code. I recently wrote a post trying to demo how to [model an Order](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2014/04/29/-Modelling-DDD-Behaviour-And-Use-Cases-By-Example.aspx) in DDD, maybe it will help you understand better

Comment: ok, more simple case: Result Class has Rating property but Rating exists even without any Result and it must be created without any reference to Result. First operation of my user is to populate all this LookupTable so how can i obly to go through a Result?

Comment: P.S. i post only a little example, at this moment the model includes around 150 entities and it's printed on 12 A3 papers

Comment: What Mike mentioned is very important. Try to think in domain language expressed as code. I doubt that your users would really talk about "populating a lookup table". That's DB-centric CRUD thinking, which you should try to avoid when designing your domain. (I know it's hard in the beginning.) Anyway, maybe you should head over to a DDD forum or mailing list and ask around there. This is not a technical question, but rather a discussion, isn't it?

Comment: the technical question is all about lookup table: according to DDD Activity must have start(date), end(date), suspend(date)... method wich create correct ActivityStatus object but if user says : "i want to be able to create new status without mod to program" i can only have a SetStatus(Status, date)  method wich create a generic status and i see poor DDD chance in thats way

Answer (score 2):

If you're eager to code and believe you understand the domain well, I would suggest a BDD test-first approach. Use tools like [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) to describe your business processes in plain english, then gradually fill in the steps and functionality as you go, using mocks, design patterns, inversion of control etc.

Background reading is a **must** if you're unfamiliar with DDD. Read the book that EagleBeak suggests, get clued up on [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles and experiment yourself.

Comment: i read the book and the other i wrote, i give a try to specflow (resign since my documentation must be writed in italian and pass to simple Nunit), use Moq, Nhibernate, Ninject to separate layer, MVVM for UI... but entity design remains the one i post above :(

Comment: SpecFlow is just a layer on top of a testing framework - it compiles down to either Nunit or MSTest. It is incredibly effective at defining the business interactions, and it is language-agnostic. You can write SpecFlow definitions in Italian if you wish, just so long as you can parse your steps with simple regular expressions.

If this is too tall a task, write an explanation down on paper of what you are attempting to accomplish and code some faling tests to this effect. Do not worry about implementation. Get the language right first.

Comment: maybe i will give it a second chance, i will try to study this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82891/BDD-using-SpecFlow-on-ASP-NET-MVC-Application and http://www.infoq.com/articles/Spec-Flow

Answer (score 1):

I can´t tell if there are better ways but what you said would be one way to solve this problem in a DDD fashion.

In my data access layer I typically use an abstract factory of respositories. This way I can plug an specific implementation for data access such as NHibernate.

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory {
  T Repository<T>();
};

public class NHibernateRepositoryFactory {
  T Repository<T>() {
    ..... // find class that implements T in Assemblies with reflection
    return repository;
  }
};

public static class Persistence {
  IRepositoryFactory Factory { get; set; }
};
```

This way you can call your repository without referencing any specific implementation:

```
User user = Persistence.Factory.Get<IUserRepository>().FindByEmail("john@tt.com");
user.name = "James";
Persistence.Factory.Get<IUserRepository>().save(user);
```

Another advantage of using abstract factories for repositories as above is that you can test your code by pluging a fake implementation for the repository.

```
public class FakeRepositoryFactory {
  T Repository<T>() {
    ..... // find class that implements T in Assemblies of fake repositories
    return repository;
  }
};

public class FakeUserRepository : public IUserRepository {
    User FindByEmail(string email) {
      // create mocked user for testing purposes ....
      return userMock;
    }
};
```

Your code will not and should not know where the user data is coming from with abstract factories for persistence. This way switch from one way to another can be done in a transparent way.

Comment: i do a similar things but with UoW pattern, i have an IUnitOfWork interface  which expose all repository interfaces. in this way there is no nedd of reflection.
At this point I decided to put these interfaces of the domain layer so i can left entities ignorant about data access implementation. All ok but my question was about domain model,not how to persist it

Comment: Perhaps I got your question now. One problem I faced is when a domain object needed to access the data layer in order to accomplish a certain business logic. Usually for verification.  Stupid example: user.setEmail("unique@email.com") setEmail method needs to go to data access layer to check if email was unique among all users otherwise an exception could be thrown. Therefore I personally believe domain objects need to access UoW or something at some point. If you dont do this the business flow in domain objects will have to be broken where some data access is needed.